# Upgrade java 8 to java 18 in linux

Tags: linux, java

I want to upgrade the java 8.0 to java 18 the latest one I tried below steps in linux

1. `wget -c --header 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' https://download.oracle.com/java/18/latest/jdk-18_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
2. `tar xvzf jdk-18_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
3. `ln -S /usr/bin/java jdk-18/bin/java`

But It is not work not upgrade to java 18

still java --version gave java 8

Any help how to upgrade java 8 to java 18

Also tried alternatives install

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The problem is how can I upgrade java 8 to java 18 Please help me in linux I gave all the comments I tried but it is not updated